# export APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND on none dangerous?

Tags: debian, debian-buster

To upgrade my Debian I make that

```
export APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=none
```

I would if there is a specific consequence on that and if it's dangegrous to set to none

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The risk is that you can be unaware of some important information, such as change in configuration files, removal of deprecated features, ....

But if you keep inform by other means, there is no risk.

Comment: The command in your question set the value `APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND` only for the current shell. To cancel the value run `export APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND=`